# iMessage App to detect if receiver has the same app installed

Tags: iphone, ios10, imessage

I am trying to develop an iMessage app on iOS 10 devices.

Was wondering if there is anyway that i can detect if receiver has my app installed or not?

Coz i want to perform certain actions if its installed and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this link : 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessage

You can read this :

> **iOS device with the iMessage app installed.**
>
> If the extension is not running, the system launches it using the
>   init(session:) presentation style. The conversation’s selectedMessage
>   property is set to the tapped message, and the view controller’s
>   willBecomeActive(with:) and didBecomeActive(with:) methods are called.
>
> If the extension is running, the system calls the view controller’s
>   willSelect(*:conversation:) method. It then updates the conversation’s
>   selectedMessage property and calls the view controller’s
>   didSelect(*:conversation:) method.
>
> Override willSelect(*:conversation:) or didSelect(*:conversation:) to
>   respond to the user selecting a new message.
>
> You can also save messages to the file system and process them later.
>
> **iOS device without the iMessage app installed.**
>
> The system opens the
>   App Store for iMessage and prompts the user to install the iMessage
>   app.

So to sum up, iMessage will detect for you if the user has already the app or not. But you won't be able to custom actions for the part where the user doesn't have the app. If the user does have the app, you can do whatever you want when he taps on your iMessage.

Comment: thanks, that sums up what i need to know. seems all i need to do is always assume receiver has my app installed, otherwise ios prompts app store.

Comment: exact, you got it ;)

Comment: What if I want the user without the app installed to have the url open in safari instead of being directed to app store? Is that possible?

Comment: Hum... for me it's an sdk behavior. So it's completely handle by Apple, it will open the Appstore if the app is not install on the user phone (if it's a message coming from your imessage app).

Comment: in my case it opens the app store but also I want to direct user to my app installation screen. how can i do that?

Comment: This should be automatic. Is your app on the applestore or just in dev? If it's not on the applestore, the rederict url does not exist yet, so it will fail to calll your installation page. You'll have to trust Apple for that part :)